# win32com how to access excel sheet by name

Tags: python, vba, win32com

I have an Excel file that contains 50+ sheets. I also have a Word document that contains some of sheet names of the Excel file. What i want to do is to iterate over the sheets that are in the Word file (within a column of a table). Below is my current code:

```
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('path_to_excel')
word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Applicatin')
doc = word.ActiveDocument

for row in range(2, doc.Tables(2).Rows.Count+1):   #Tables(2) is the table in word contains the sheet name
    tmp = doc.Tables(2).Cell(row, 1).Range.Text.split(r'(')[0]  #I got the sheet name in that column
    ws = wb.Sheets.Item(tmp) ---------------> this is where I have issue with, i tried with wb.Workshees(tmp) and does not work either
    ws.Range("A1:B2").CurrentRegion.Copy()
    doc.Tables(2).Cell(row, 2).Range.PasteExcelTable(False, False, True)
```

So what is the correct way to access a sheet by its name? I know index will work but that will be hardcoded.

Comment: `wb.Worksheets(tmp)` should work as long as `tmp` is a valid sheet name